# Bulk update in PostgreSQL by unnesting a JSON array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to do a batch update in PostgreSQL in one go by passing in an array of JSON objects, but I am not sure how I should approach the problem.

An example:

```
[
  { "oldId": 25, "newId": 30 },
  { "oldId": 41, "newId": 53 }
]
```

should resolve as:
`UPDATE table SET id = 30 WHERE id = 25` and `UPDATE table SET id = 41 WHERE id = 53`, in a single command, of course.

Comment: There is no table (definition) in your question. Only something that looks like json. and some text.

Comment: I am not sure how this question is schema specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function `jsonb_array_elements()` in the from clause:

```sql
update my_table
set id = (elem->'newId')::int
from jsonb_array_elements(
    '[
      { "oldId": 25, "newId": 30 },
      { "oldId": 41, "newId": 50 }
    ]') as elem
where id = (elem->'oldId')::int
```

Note that if the column `id` is unique (primary key) the update may result in a duplication error depending on the data provided.

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=634d721730cdc95b3621f0d46408d7a4)

Answer (score 2):

You need to unnest the array the cast the elements to the proper data type:

```
update the_table
   set id = (x.item ->> 'newId')::int
from jsonb_array_elements('[...]') x(item)
where the_table.id = (x.item ->> 'oldId')::int
```